# Extract .xlsx files from folder with OR condition

Tags: vba, excel

This code extracts files with names like "M*", and I'd like it to also pull files with names like "X*". Can I simply set an OR condition on the filename parameter? Thanks for your advice!

```
Worksheets("PMNs").Range("A2:A500").Clear
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim Filename, Pathname As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "M*.xlsm")

x = 1
Range("A1").Select
Do While Filename <> ""
    x = x + 1
    ' MsgBox (Filename)
    Windows("Resource Load Data_fy18.xlsm").Activate 'open data file
    Sheets("PMNs").Select
    ActiveCell(A & x).Value = Filename 'copy filename to next cell Ax
    Filename = Dir()
Loop

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("A2:A" & lastrow), _
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly change the way you open the files:

```
Dim Filename as String, Pathname As String
Dim wb      As Workbook
Dim ws      As Worksheet

Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

x = 1
Range("A1").Select
Dim StrFile As String
StrFile = Dir(Pathname)
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    If (Left(StrFile, 1) = "M" Or Left(StrFile, 1) = "X") and right(StrFile,4) = "xlsm" Then
        Debug.print(StrFile) ' prints the file name and extension
        ' Do stuff here!
    End If
    Filename = Dir
Loop
```